# Unable to add Parse_JSON schema in power automate

Tags: json, api, power-automate

[image]

I have an error with my flow - Action 'Parse_JSON' failed

I'm getting an validation failed error when adding the following schema.

```
{
    "type": "array",
    "items": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "id": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "canUpdate": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "canDelete": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "canArchive": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "hasChildren": {
                "type": "boolean"
            },
            "info": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "key": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "value": {
                            "type": "integer"
                        },
                        "valueClass": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "valueCaption": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "keyCaption": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "key",
                        "value",
                        "valueClass",
                        "valueCaption",
                        "keyCaption"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "required": [
            "id",
            "canUpdate",
            "canDelete",
            "canArchive",
            "hasChildren",
            "info"
        ]
    }
}
```

Need to allocate this Json schema to create a sharepoint list. But unable to add the above json schema.

Error:

```
[
  {
    "message": "Invalid type. Expected Integer but got String.",
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "linePosition": 0,
    "path": "[0].info[1].value",
    "value": "device return from mds\n5CG8161K7W\nUNI-LT-MTR019\tPavaniH\n5CG9034BVZ\nUNI-LT-COR002\nNishanG\n\n5CG8161KNF\nUNI-LT-MTR016\tSachiniwe \n\nRequest user: kumudug_c@masholdings.com \nSubmit user: madhushand_c@masholdings.com \n- Via SmartDesk PowerApp",
    "schemaId": "#/items/properties/info/items/properties/value",
    "errorType": "type",
    "childErrors": []
  },
  {
    "message": "Invalid type. Expected Integer but got String.",
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "linePosition": 0,
    "path": "[0].info[2].value",
    "value": "device return from mds",
    "schemaId": "#/items/properties/info/items/properties/value",
    "errorType": "type",
    "childErrors": []
  },
  {
    "message": "Invalid type. Expected Integer but got String.",
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "linePosition": 0,
    "path": "[1].info[1].value",
    "value": "payment for dialog add line",
    "schemaId": "#/items/properties/info/items/properties/value",
    "errorType": "type",
    "childErrors": []
  },
  {
    "message": "Invalid type. Expected Integer but got String.",
    "lineNumber": 0,
    "linePosition": 0,
    "path": "[1].info[2].value",
    "value": "payment  - 7458",
    "schemaId": "#/items/properties/info/items/properties/value",
    "errorType": "type",
    "childErrors": []
  }
]
```

Comment: That's not a payload, that's a schema definition.  Can you show us your error?  Too hard to help without it.

Comment: It's Prompting a Schema Validation Failed error.
ValidationFailed. The schema validation failed.

Comment: Well the error is pretty clear. You're saying `#/items/properties/info/items/properties/value` is integer, but it got a string. So, which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that for your field it is being passed an actual integer and not an integer surrounded with double quotes (i.e. 22, not "22") -- alternatively you can change "integer" to "string" if the Flow doesn't care one way or another.

[image: Screenshot of your schema where the error is being raised]